# regular expression for accepting INTEGERS followed by SLASH Followed by INTEGERS in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate a value from html form in JavaScript function, the format is a bit flexible.

i.e,

1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 integer value followed by back slash(/) followed by 1 or 2 or 3 integers.

Example.

`12345/123`  is a valid value.

`1234/12`  is a valid value.

`123/123`  is a valid value.

`1/1`  is a valid value.

`a/123`   is NOT a valid value.

`123/%` in NOT a valid value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good start to learn about regular expressions.

Comment: regular expressions are something that i m not comfortable with it, Also i am short on deadline so can't afford time to create one, thats why i asked here. the link looks fantastic, i will definitely look into it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex: `^\d{1,5}\/\d{1,3}$`

Example:

```
var re = /^\d{1,5}\/\d{1,3}$/;

console.log(re.test('12345/123')); // true
console.log(re.test('1234/12')); // true
console.log(re.test('123/1')); // true
console.log(re.test('12/123')); // true
console.log(re.test('1/123')); // true
console.log(re.test('a/123')); // false
console.log(re.test('123456/123'); // false
```

That said, you should start from the basics:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Here you can find many examples: http://regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: Perhaps add the start and end characters to your regex, otherwise e.g.: `console.log( /\d{1,5}\/\d{1,3}/.test('99912345/123999') ); // true`, i.e. use `/^\d{1,5}\/\d{1,3}$/`

Comment: yeah, thanks @MikeM. In hurry I totally forgot about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You know, consulting the documentation isn't too much to ask sometimes ...

```
\d{1,5}/\d{1,3}
```

There are also good sites out there to learn regular expressions, such as [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: thank you for the reply and your time :)regular expressions is always the scary thing for me, thats why i asked to make sure i get the right result.